# PowerPoint VBA for tagging objects and dynamically updating text box slide references

Tags: vba, reference, tags, powerpoint

Wondering if there is a macro that could automatically update slide references for objects on other slides.

For instance, let’s say there is a table on slide X. I want to be able to place a text box on slide 5 and say “refer to page X.”

These presentations are printed so using hyperlinks would not work. We do not want to hard code the reference because if we add/delete slides, we do not want to go back and manually update all the references.

My VBA knowledge is very limited. Not sure how to "tag" an object and then reference it.

Answer (score 0):

To tag a shape, assuming it's currently selected:

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
   .Tags.Add "TagName", "TagValue"
End With
```

So for example, select the table and:

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
   .Tags.Add "ShapeTag", "Table1"
   ' the value above should be unique
End With
```

Hooking the text that you want to update up to the table will be a bit trickier. I'd approach it by adding two tags to the text shape, the first being the text you want to appear in the text box, but with the slide number included as a replaceable parameter; the next tag would be a reference to the shape in question:

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
   .Tags.Add "Text", "Refer to page #page#"
   .Tags.Add "Shape", "Table1"
End With
```

To update, you'd run code that checks each shape on each slide and if the shape has Len(.Tags("Shape")) > 0 you'd call a function that looks at each slide/each shape and returns the slide number where it finds a shape tagged "Table1".

You'd then substitute the slide number in place of #page# in the .Text tag and apply that as the shape's .TextFrame.TextRange.Text